# Which M.. tier do I need for my app (MongoDB)?

Tags: database, mongodb

I’m new to MongoDB,

I have an Ionic App for a local restaurant where you have some products which you can order. The app also have a register to create some users. There is also a Angular Web App where you can put in products and look up users etc.

Both apps are connected to the MongoDB. Unfortunately I don’t have any clue which data plan is necessary for the deployment of these two apps.

Is it maybe better to switch to Firebase?

Can anybody help me please?

Best regards
Basti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting a tier in [MongoDB-Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas) depends on various factors like data size, IOPS, Price etc.. As you're saying this is for a local restaurant & I would assume there could be less traffic to the App, then in that case you can go with `M10` cause that's where MongoDB Atlas really provide some valuable features to database which is used in production environment. For development environment you can give a try with `M5` cluster. Some features you can enjoy using `M10` or above are :

1. **Dedicated Cluster :** Clusters deploy each `mongod` process to its own instance, Where as `M0`, `M2` & `M5` are in shared environment, So Atlas will automatically upgrade the cluster to latest version upon availability which is not preferred in realtime Apps as there could be a functionality/package that can break with upgrades.
2. **Queryable backups :** You can take advantage of querying specific continuous backup snapshot, Which is really helpful to restore a part of data instead of entire dataset which is back'd up a day ago.
3. **Supports Network Peering :** As most of projects now a days use cloud platforms to deploy Apps, Clusters >= `M10` supports network peering.
4. **Metrics & Performance Advisor :** This is one most important thing which you'll get benefited using clusters >= `M10`. Using alerts you'll get to know which kind of queries are taking much time, How many connections are open at a given time, monitor CPU threshold & get alerted, additionally MongoDB can suggest you with indexes to be created for better performance of queries being run on collections which fail to use index already present in.

At the end of the day, Remaining most other features remain almost same. From my experience usually you'll estimate & pre-pay certain amount for MongoDB Atlas account for around 3 years, Where you don't get back anything if you've not utilized all of it. Also you can upgrade & downgrade clusters at anytime manually or can be automatically scaled up or down based on incoming traffic.

**Ref :** [cluster-tier](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/cluster-tier/#cluster-tier)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what do you think about firebase. Is it cheaper than MongoDB?

Comment: @basti38 : I have no idea on firebase, but I can say you'll get better support from MongoDB community as it's one of the best in leading databases out there ! Since it's hosted & maintained by MongoDB it might be bit costly than self hosted DB but I would say it's worth it if you wanted to kick start with minimal effort. From my exp. I would say it wouldn't be much pricey, would assume around 3k $/month for 3(dev/qa/prod) `M10` clusters. You can calculate the costs from reference link provided above or get support from them.